# How to gracefully shutdown emacs daemon?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, emacs23

On login to Ubuntu, I start an Emacs (version 23) daemon using Ubuntu's Startup programs. I then start Emacs clients whenever I need to edit something. When I logoff from Ubuntu, it says Emacs is still running, of course. I need to attach a script somewhere to tell Gnome to shutdown emacs when I logoff/shutdown.

1) What should the script look like? "kill-emacs" doesn't seem to work.

2) Where should I put this script? There's nothing in the startup programs (System->Sessions menu) panel that looks useful. I'd prefer something that works in the user's account, rather than hacking the PostSession script or something else with root access.

Comment: [While you wait for a real answer] Something like: emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)" will do it. (You might want save-buffers-kill-emacs instead; that asks for confirmation first.)

Comment: Does putting something that ShreevatsaR say in .bash_logout work?  I forget.  Does that only fire when a login shell is exited?

Comment: It's rather a question for SU as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @seth: .bash_logout runs when the login shell is exited,, which is after Gnome shuts down
@Torok: superuser is in private beta. until then, this is all I've got.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This linuxquestions.org page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/gnome-run-script-on-logout-724453) has a Python script that can be run during login that listens for the 'save yourself' event that Gnome emits during shutdown. You could modify that to do the:

```
emacsclient -e '(save-buffers-kill-emacs)'
```

Official docs: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc8

Comment: I tested it under Ubuntu 11.10 and it works great!

Comment: If your system doesn't have a "save yourself" event, you can fake one by running a shell script on startup that traps on `EXIT` and reads from a fifo that you create for the purpose. The script will idle until trapping and then can run any function you assign -- such as one that calls `emacsclient -e "(save-buffers-kill-emacs)"`

Comment: Is there  any way to check emacs daemon running on the background before running this line, where when I run it if emacs does not work on the background it logs long messages @genehack

Answer (score 42):

ShreevatsaR is right, the answer is `kill-emacs` or `save-buffers-kill-emacs`, both of which are interactive, and so can be run from within Emacs with `M-x save-buffers-kill-emacs`. This is probably the best way to do it, since you will get to save modified files.

Another alternative is to make a shell file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)"
```

Which you can run from wherever you like (menu icon, panel, etc).

Comment: I think what the questioner wants is something that can be put in a place that is automatically executed when GNOME is asked to log out. (So it's more of a Gnome/Ubuntu/X question than an Emacs question, actually.)

Comment: Is there a specific signal that the emacs daemon will listen to shutdown?

Comment: `sudo killall emacs` also works @haxney

Answer (score 10):

Another addendum to ShreevatsaR: the python script works like a charm, but I'd suggest using

```
emacsclient -e '(let ((last-nonmenu-event nil))(save-buffers-kill-emacs))'
```

as command. Setting last-nonmenu-event to nil forces emacs into mouse-mode, so you get "nice" dialog boxes instead of prompts in the minibuffer.

Or even more fancy (somewhere in your emacs config):

```
(defun shutdown-emacs-server () (interactive)
  (when (not (eq window-system 'x))
    (message "Initializing x windows system.")
    (x-initialize-window-system)
    (when (not x-display-name) (setq x-display-name (getenv "DISPLAY")))
    (select-frame (make-frame-on-display display '((window-system . x))))
  )
  (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil)(window-system "x"))(save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
```

and then:

```
emacsclient -e '(shutdown-emacs-server)'
```

Comment: Does it work if launched in a terminal? It keeps telling me:
*ERROR*: Assertion failed: (not x-initialized)

Answer (score 7):

If you use **systemd** you may be interested in this unit file that lets you manage an Emacs server gracefully from within your console/remote system:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Restart=always

# Remove the limit in startup timeout, since emacs
# cloning and building all packages can take time
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

(it kills the daemon in the same way folks already suggested above.)

You could put and name the unit file like ~/.config/systemd/user/emacs.service so it's bind to your user instead running it as root; to manage it:

$ systemctl --user {enable,disable,start,restart,stop} emacs.service

Please note: I took this note from somewhere else, can't remember where though.

Comment: It's from the Emacs wiki. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon

Answer (score 4):

I think that using a script in /etc/init.d is a cleaner solution.
Check here for more details 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon

Comment: Perhaps, but only if you're the only user of that machine. Even then it seems a little kludgey to have to specify a user the way presented there.

Answer (score 3):

the answer from willert contains a small bug. it must look like

```
(defun shutdown-emacs-server () (interactive)
  (when (not (eq window-system 'x))
    (message "Initializing x windows system.")
    (x-initialize-window-system)
    (when (not x-display-name) (setq x-display-name (getenv "DISPLAY")))
    (select-frame (make-frame-on-display x-display-name '((window-system . x))))
  )
  (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil)(window-system "x"))(save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put `emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)"` in GDM's PostSession directory or directly in the Default script:

```
/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default
```

see also [GDM documentation](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#scripting).

Comment: Thanks, but my post says I didn't want to use PostSession because it requires (AFAIK) root access to modify it. If a user can add something in autostart, there should  be a way to add something to "autoshutdown".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most general solution would be to put a script in the system PostSession directory that runs every executable script in ~/.logout-d, or something similar. Then you can put whatever scripts you like in ~/.logout-d, and they will be run on logout.

The script might be as simple as `run-parts ~/.logout.d`.

Note: Untested, though I do use a startup script that does `run-parts ~/.autostart.d`, and that's been working fine forever.

Edit: Of course, it would be just as easy to modify the above python script to execute that same command, but I personally don't like the idea of loading a script for my entire session just to run commands on logout.

Answer (score -2):

Just open some terminal and `pkill -TERM emacs`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738178/148680) for why that's not a solution.