# Emacsclient hook on kill

Tags: emacs, kill, emacsclient

I am trying to find a hook in Emacs, which should fire right before emacs server graceful shutdown.
I tried kill-emacs-query-functions, kill-emacs-hook, server-done-hook with elisp like :

```
(add-hook 'server-done-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (savehist-save)
             )
          )
```

... but none of them is called when OS shuts down, so history is not saved.

Maybe someone could give a hint?

P.S. I am on Gentoo Linux, emacs-vcs-23.2.9999 package, terminal only. For testing desired behaviour Emacs is stopped using start-stop-daemon utility.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since [Emacs 24.1](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.24), Emacs runs [`kill-emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html#index-kill_002demacs-5126) which runs the functions in [`kill-emacs-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html#index-kill_002demacs_002dhook-5131). So the question, and the rest of this answer, are only relevant to older versions.

The right place to run something before Emacs shuts down is either `kill-emacs-query-function` if you want to be able to cancel the shutdown or `kill-emacs-hook` if you don't. The problem you're facing is that your OS does not notify Emacs to shut down gracefully in a way that Emacs understands, or to look at it the other way, Emacs does not understand your OS's request to suht down gracefully.

A graceful way of shutting down Emacs 23 from the outside is to run `emacsclient -n -e '(kill-emacs)'`. That's obviously not a generic way of telling a program to shut down gracefully.

The normal way to shut down a process gracefully on unix is to send it a SIGHUP or SIGTERM signal. Unfortunately, Emacs treats almost all signals as fatal, and only runs an emergency auto save and no lisp code when it receives them. This is not configurable from lisp. [A different behavior has been requested, but turned down](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-01/msg00617.html).

A partial workaround ([found here](http://www.doitian.com/2009/08/run-kill-emacs-hook-in-emacs-daemon/)) is to run session saving hooks in `delete-frame-functions`. This hook is likely to be run before the system shutdown sequence, either when you close your last frame or when the X server dies (taking your terminals with them if you run Emacs in a terminal). Make sure you don't run the hook that kills the server in `delete-frame-functions`.

By the way, if you were going to use this exact hook, note that your code is a complicated way of writing `(add-hook 'server-done-hook 'savehist-save)`, and that's not useful since there's already `savehist-autosave` in `kill-emacs-hook`.

Comment: I added OS info. Yes, I know it's a bit complex then needs to be.

Comment: If you sent to emacs a QUIT signal, emacs can shutdown gracefully as `(kill-emacs)` does. e.g.  pkill -3 emacs OR pkill -QUIT emacs, Unfortunately, some OS sent TERM signal, emacs not work well with it.

Comment: n.b. Starting from Emacs 24.1, "Emacs now calls `kill-emacs` if it receives SIGTERM or SIGHUP, or if it receives a SIGINT signal in batch mode.  `kill-emacs-hook` is now also run in batch mode."  See `etc/NEWS.24` and also `C-h i g (elisp)Killing Emacs`.