# Why is it important to shutdown emacs daemon gracefully?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, daemon

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167484/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-emacs-daemon) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737207/emacsclient-hook-on-kill?noredirect=1&lq=1), they discuss how shuting down emacs deamon gracefully. Why is it important? One of the answers suggested pkill -TERM emacs, which does the job but apparently not gracefully. What is the problem with not shuting down emacs daemon gracefully? what can happen if I don't do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think it may be important to keep updated recent opened files list (or updated emacs history file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of the answers suggested `pkill -TERM emacs`, which does the job but apparently not gracefully.

Notwithstanding that I would *recommend* using the process ID rather than `pkill`, that *should* be a graceful shut-down.  The manual says:

> The ‘kill-emacs’ function is normally called via the higher-level
>   command ‘C-x C-c’ (‘save-buffers-kill-terminal’).  *Note
>   (emacs)Exiting::.  It is also called automatically if Emacs receives a
>   ‘SIGTERM’ or ‘SIGHUP’ operating system signal (e.g., when the
>   controlling terminal is disconnected), or if it receives a ‘SIGINT’
>   signal while running in batch mode (*note Batch Mode::).

This behaviour was introduced in Emacs 24.1 (which post-dates the Q&A you've linked to).

> ** Exiting changes
>
> *** Emacs now calls `kill-emacs' if it receives SIGTERM or SIGHUP,
>   or if it receives a SIGINT signal in batch mode.
>
> *** `kill-emacs-hook' is now also run in batch mode.
>   Third-party code which adds to `kill-emacs-hook' should check if they
>   do the right thing in batch mode.

---

As to why you wouldn't want a non-graceful shutdown, that's not really an Emacs question.  Killing processes without allowing them any chance to clean up should always be a last resort.  It's not difficult to imagine the problems which might result if a process was killed in the middle of writing a file, for instance.